# Before certified GPS, how much did a full IFR panel cost?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, avionics, flight-instruments

Certified IFR GPS navigators are expensive, but the price of even used HSIs and DME seem to bring some perspective to that cost. How much did a full IFR upgrade cost back in the day before GPS?

Comment: That's really difficult to quantify because in the 70s and 80s normal avionics were probably double/triple the cost, in constant dollars, of the same capability components today.  I have an ad for a crappy little Narco 1 1/2 nav/com marketed for basic GA airplanes called the Escort 110 from about 1975.  The thing, which was ultra basic, was 495 in 1975 dollars; 2500 today.  You might have paid nearly 1000 back then for a VOR receiver and head, 5 grand today.  So maybe someone spent 6-10k to put a full IFR panel in their 172 in 1980, or about 20-30 grand today.  So think the answer is, a LOT.

Comment: This should be easy to quantify, if anyone happens to remember: Before production ended in 1986, how much more did a Cessna 172 cost with a stock IFR panel, vs one with a stock VFR panel?

Comment: @rgfuller Easy? Costs $600 for a 1 year sub to Aerobluebook. They seem to be the only ones collecting this historical price info.